# Using `navigation.navigateUp` incorrectly displays burger menu

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

I have an activity that is setup to work with Android Jetpack's [`NavigationUI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI). This works well and I can navigate correctly except that if I navigate down 2 times, when I navigate up once, the app bar will shows the burger even though there's still one fragment in the `childFragmentManager`'s backstack.

Example:

[image]

I navigate to the *Alice In Animation* RSS feed (this is an RSS reader), then to the *Love death & robots* article of the feed. Then go back to the articles list. But I'm not yet at the top of the application. There should not be a burger menu here.

Here's my activity class:

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    private val navigation: NavController by lazy {
        Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.main_activity_host_fragment)
    }

    private val drawerLayout by lazy {
        findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.activity_main_navigation_drawer)
    }

    private val drawerToggle by lazy {
        ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
    }

    private val appBarConfiguration by lazy {
        AppBarConfiguration(navigation.graph, drawerLayout)
    }

    private val backstackCount inline get() = main_activity_host_fragment?.childFragmentManager?.backStackEntryCount ?: 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navigation, appBarConfiguration)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        if(item?.itemId == android.R.id.home && backstackCount == 0) {
            val isOpened = drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(activity_main_navigation_view)
            if(isOpened) drawerLayout.closeDrawers()
            else drawerLayout.openDrawer(activity_main_navigation_view)

            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val result = navigation.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
        drawerToggle.syncState()
        return result
    }
}
```

Here is my navigation graph:

[image]

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer) specifically call out that you shouldn't be using `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. Why do you have that code in your activity?

Comment: Dammit... I've been on this for days. How could I missed that. Thank you.

Comment: @ianhanniballake In this configuration, the burger menu is not animated anymore when the drawer opens and closes. Is it possible to configure this?

Comment: For a [modal drawer](https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer/#modal-drawer), the navigation menu icon would be covered by the drawer, so you wouldn't see the icon at all when the drawer is opening/closing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ianhanniballake commented, `NavigationUI` handles the home button automatically. `ActionBarDrawerToggle` shouldn't be used with `AppBarConfiguration`.